# Link State List Drop Down HTML to a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dropdown, statelist

I have added a drop down state list to my home page, which uses wordpress/elemntor.

When an item is selected from the dropdown list I would like to redirect the user to another URL. For example, when Georgia is selected I would like to redirect to this URL: https://www.everlastingopportunities.com/georgia/

How do I make the page go to the above URL when Georgia selected in drop down?

```html
<select>
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
 <option value="CA">California</option>
 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
 <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <!-- ... list continues ... -->
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: We need a little more info from you first. You need an if statement to make a decision based on what you choose, and those aren't done in HTML.

Comment: @Jay, I got this from freeformatter.com and copied and pasted in elementor css box. The state drop down list is on my home page but when I choose a state it does not do anything. I am not sure what asp.net. How can I incorporate a if statement? I googled but I don't understand. I might just have to take it off until someone makes a youtube video.

Comment: the list looks fine, but there has to be more to it than just that, there has to be some logic somewhere so you can tell it what to do when you click. Let's see if we can figure this out, are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Wordpress I can screen shot but I don't think I can upload on this chat. But under advance options it has this on each web page.
Z-Index
CSS ID
CSS Classes

Comment: under content it just says "enter code" which is the code I provided above is what I entered which gave me the drop down. Under Advance options it has z-index/css id/css classes but I tried to add this to the state code <a href="https://www.everlastingopportunities.com/georgia/">Visit everlastingopportunities.com!</a> but it did not work

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Wordpress and I don't want to make it more confusing so I'm going to bow out. As a parting comment I will say that I think of z-index like layers on the page, say you have 2 images and they're both trying to take up the same spot on your page. The one with the higher z-index is the one that you'll see.

Comment: @Jay Thank you! I will just add the states to the main menu for now.

Comment: It works now! I just came back to put the answer just in case someone else needs to know. <option value="https://www.everlastingopportunities.com/georgia/">Georgia (GA)</option>

Comment: <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Please select</option>
 <option value="http://www.everlastingopportunities.com/alabama/">Alabama (AL)</option> (THIS IS WHAT IS BEFORE THE ORIGINAL FIRST LINE OF THE TEXT ABOVE).

Comment: Good work, I'm glad you got it  ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by passing the selected option to the javascript function and using it to redirect to the new url.

Ideal is to add a blank option on top, so that the person who wants Alabama as option makes a choice once.

I have made the script based on visible name as you showed in the question.

```js
function my_function(event) {
  var options = event.target.options;
  var selected = options[options.selectedIndex].text;
  window.location.href = 'https://www.everlastingopportunities.com/' + selected + '/';
}
```

```html
<select onchange="my_function(event)">
 <option value="">---</option>
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
 <option value="CA">California</option>
 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
 <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <!-- ... list continues ... -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy do it with jQuery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCountry">
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <!-- ... list continues ... -->
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#selectCountry").change(function(){
    window.location.href = "https://www.everlastingopportunities.com/" + $("#selectCountry > option:selected").text() + "/";
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and past Code from post above for the full code and enter website links.

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="everlastingopportunities.com/Alabama/">Alabama (AL)</option>
    <option value="(ENTER WEBSITE LINK HERE)">Alaska (AK)</option>
    <option value="(ENTERWEBSITE LINK HERE)">Arizona (AZ)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <label f`enter code here`or="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-select">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>
            <!-- option -->
          <option value="---">---</option>
          <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
          <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
          <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
          <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="California">California</option>
          <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
          <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
          <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
          <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
          <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
          <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
          <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
          <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
          <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
          <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
          <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
          <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
          <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
          <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
          <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
          <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
          <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>`enter code here`
          <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="New York">New York</option>
          <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="Northern Marianas Islands">Northern Marianas Islands</option>
          <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
          <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
          <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
          <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
          <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
          <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
          <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
          <option value="Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands</option>
          <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
          <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
          <!-- option -->
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.